# how to fix this "Failed to build pycocotools" error

Tags: python, c++, pycocotools

while i am trying to install pycocotools. it resulted in this error :-

```
    enter code here
Building wheels for collected packages: pycocotools
  Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build pycocotools
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  running build_ext
  skipping 'pycocotools\_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

EVEN THOUHGH I INSTALLED VC++_2015 BUT AGAIN THE SAME ERROR IS COMING

PLEASE ANY BODY HELP ME PLEASE.

Comment: Do you run the pip - command from a Visual Studio command prompt? This might solve your problem.

Comment: No can you please tell me how should i do that

Comment: You go to the windows - menu (or start - menu in former windows versions) and you look for the folder of your Visual Studio Installation.  There you will find the "Developer Command Prompt of Visual Studio <e.g. 2022>" Open that and retry what you did before.

Please excuse the very late answer.

Comment: You should install Visual Studio Build Tools from the following link
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ which is different product from Visual Studio C++